# jQuery - appending XML - IE8 throws "Object doesn't support this property or method" error - FF works

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8

Using jQuery 1.9.1 and creating XML similar to below.  It gets built from items in an array of checkboxes on the page that are checked.  The XML structure is:

```
<MyXML>
   <Msg>This is a test message.</Msg>
   <MsgTime>2013-10-15 08:30:00.000</MsgTime>
   <Locations>
      <Location>Panel1</Location>
      <Location>Panel2</Location>
      <Location>Panel3</Location>
   </Locations>
</MyXML>
```

When a submit button is clicked, all the checked checkboxes are pushed into an array, which I then loop through to create the `<Location>` XML nodes.  Right before I loop through that array, I find & remove any existing `Location` in the XML.

```
zXML.find("Location").remove();

for (var d=0; d < msgArr.length; d= d+ 1) {
    var tmpLocNode = "<Location>" + msgArr[d].locID + "</Location>";
    zXML.find("Locations").append( tmpLocNode );
    }
```

In FF, the above code works great.

However, in IE8, the last line in the for loop:

```
zXML.find("Locations").append( tmpLocNode );
```

throws an error, "Object doesn't support this property or method" and stops at line 6470 in the jquery.js module.  That line is:

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[1] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[2];
```

and is in the `ELSE` part of `// Convert html into DOM nodes` in the jquery module.

Any idea what the issue might be?  I suspect it is IE8 not liking XML, but not sure how to resolve this issue.  Would appreciate any feedback or thoughts on a better way to do what I am doing.

Thanks!

Comment: IE8 is missing some basic functionality. I would try jQuery 1.10, and if that doesn't work, just show IE8 users a message telling them to upgrade. Make the world a better place one browser at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this will work, but all I can suggest is an alternate method of creating the new node, as it appears the error is in creating the node from the provided string.

```
for (var d = 0; d < msgArr.length; d = d+ 1) {
    var $tmpLocNode = $("<Location />", { text: msgArr[d].locID });
    zXML.find("Locations").append($tmpLocNode);
}
```